# Family registration using Caldera Forms

Tags: wordpress, civimember, user-account, caldera-forms

I am currently working on a form where a parent can register multiple children for a Membership. I am using Caldera Forms for this. I was able to setup different number of children and all the relationships. However, that is where things go south.

While Caldera creates an account for each person in civicrm, it does not create one on Wordpress (ideally it would do both). Also, I am unable to create a membership for each child where the child can view their own membership and the parent can view/pay for all their children.

Is something like this even possible in Caldera/CiviCRM?

Thank you for the help!